# Prompting user on package install "pip install <pkg>"

Tags: python, stdout, pip, distutils

I've created a tar.gz of a package that includes a setup.py file. setup.py uses the setup() function provided in distutils.core. I want to prompt the user when they run "pip install .tar.gz". Unfortunately, it looks like pip redirects all stdout and stderr of the "python setup.py install" command through a special log filter, which reads stdout line by line. This means I can't have a prompt such as "Email: ..." since "Email: " will not get printed until after the user has pressed enter. Also, the log filter indents every line of output, which is not ideal.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that.

If it is absolutely necessary to have information from the user during the install, ask for an environment variable to be set, and fail if it is not set. Better yet, require a plain text configure file to *run* your module - and set it with default values during the install

Don't try to make an interactive session needed during the install, because the idea of PIP and easy_install are that they also install the pre-requisites of a package - so they may install a lot of packages in a batch,. The user will just expect pip install to do its job, and an unexpected interactive prompt will ruin automated installs, pre-requiste chains, buildout installs, remote installs, and so on.

Comment: I agree that an interactive install *can* be a nuisance. In this case, I do not believe the prompt would interfere with the pre-requisite chain, as it would prompt as that package is being installed. The interactive prompt can also be bypassed (close stdin/EOF), which will limit issues with remote installs. What do you think of apt-get? There are programs that have interactive prompts despite all the potential issues you outlined. In the event the prompt fails, everything can be populated through a configuration file as you suggest. I just thought it might be easier to ask the user directly.

Comment: apt-get just s*cks in this respect. But, coming back to Python  - certain projects do use "buildout" - whcih can be used to download, install and configure hundreds of Python modules for a single isntance of a project to run. If any of those would require user intervention, it would not work. Buildout based, or otehr compelx projects certainly benefit from having an automated "build" that putz everything together in an automated server, and runs unit tests. Requiring user intervention would break this scenario as well. Each of these examples could be detailed.